# integral involve Dirac Delta "Function"

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

$$\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_0^1dy \delta (\frac{1}{2}-xy)y^2$$

Solution:

$$\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_0^1dy \delta (\frac{1}{2}-xy)y^2=\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_0^1dy \delta (x(y-\frac{1}{2x})y^2=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx\int_0^1dy \delta (y-\frac{1}{2x})y^2$$

Up to this point my solution is the same as the official solution, however,

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx \int_{0}^{1} dy \delta(y-\frac{1}{2x})y^2=\int_{1/2}^1 dx\frac{1}{x}(\frac{1}{(2x)^2})$$

Here in the official solution, the lower limit of the integral is $1/2$ and not $0$, which is what i had....Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y$ goes from 0 to 1, so if $y=\frac{1}{2x}$, $x$ must be $\geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: i pretty much forgot most things i learned in real analysis so gotta ask, does that matter, its the limit of the integral do we care about the value of x?

Comment: So if $x<1/2$ then $\int_0^1 dy \delta(y-1/2x)y^2=0$, because when $y$ is between 0 and 1, $\delta(y-1/2x)$ is always 0 in this case.

Comment: Ahhhhhh right thanks!